# Infinite loop in function handling asynchronous onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a jquery script which triggers after a user select a file for upload (the code is a little messy for debugging). 
1. After user selects a jpeg image file (`f`), then the image is loaded and its width and height are compared against the max allowed. 
2. If image is too large, then call `resize` to size down. 
3. Since image `onload` is asynchronous, a callback function `afterloading(image)` is called:

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').change(function(){
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var img; 
        var max_width = 0; 
        var max_height = 0; 
        var max_size_mb;
        var f = $(this)[0].files[0];  
        if (f != null) {
          max_width = $('#max_width').val();
          max_height = $('#max_height').val();
          max_size_mb = $('#max_size_mb').val();
          alert(max_width +', ' + max_height);
          $('#file_name').val(f.name);
          alert(f.name);
          $('#file_size').val(f.size/1024);
          $('#file_type').val(f.type);  //image/jpeg
          $('#file_extension').val(f.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase());
          alert(f.type);
          alert(f.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase());
          if (f.type == 'image/jpeg') {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
              afterloading(this);
              return false;
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(f);
          };
        };


    function afterloading(image) {
        var w = image.width, h = image.height;
        alert('hi-max' + max_width + ' -- ' + max_height);
        alert('hi' + w + ' xx ' + h);
        if (w > max_width || h > max_height) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(f);
          if (w > max_width){
            h = Math.ceil(h * max_width / w);
            w = max_width;
          } else if (h > max_height) {
            w = Math.ceil(w * max_height / h);
            h = max_height;
          };
          alert('before resize, ' + w + ' ?? ' + h );
          resize(image, w, h); 
          $('#remove').val('true');
          return false;
        };
    };

    function resize(image, width, height) {
        alert('resize');
      var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      mainCanvas.width = width;
      mainCanvas.height = height;
      var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
      $('#uploaded_file_hidden_file').val(mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")); 
      $('#file_size').val(image.size/1024);
      alert($('#file_size').val());
      alert("++" + image.size);
      return false;
    };

    return false;

});
});
```

The problem is that the execution of `afterloading(image)` causes infinite loop. What could cause the infinite loop?

UPDATE:

There is the same infinite loop after commenting out the `resize(image, w,h)` in `afterloading`. So the problem is within `afterloading` itself.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: afterloading calls resize which updates #uploaded_file_hidden_file which triggers change() on #uploaded_file_hidden_file which calls afterloading...

Comment: `Gabe Moothart`, the `.change` is on another id of `file_for_upload` and is not on `hidden_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just speculating here, since you haven't provided jsfiddle with the code above, but what is `img` loading here, and when is it loaded?

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  afterloading(this);
  return false;
};
```

`afterloading` is expecting an `image` object, and it seems to be in `f`. Try passing in `f` to `afterloading` to see if it works, given what you have above *should* do what you want.

EDIT:

Also it looks like `this` in `afterloading` is the scope of the `img` object you just created above, which is empty.

Comment: The `alert` returns the width and height of the `img` within `afterloading`. `img` must be present. Also if `img` is empty, then the `if` loop in `afterloading` will be skipped entirely.

Comment: When passing `f` instead of `this` in `afterloading`, the alert shows `undefined` for both image width and height.

Answer (score 1):

This line `$('#uploaded_file_hidden_file').val(mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));`  in the resize() function keep posting same image again and again to server and keep calling resize() from afterloading().

Try removing this and check

Comment: Commented out the line and re-start the server. The problem is the same. This line only assigns a string to the `hidden_file` element.